# Edit PDF online and save and form data to server

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, acrobat, livecycle

I have some PDF documents which are being displayed in the browser, with some fields already being pre-populated from the database using iTextSharp (we are running Windows Server 2008, IIS 7, SQL Server 2008, and ASP.NET 2.0/2.5 with C#). Our clients need to be able to fill in the remaining fields and save the PDF to the server.

I have considered the following possibilities:

1.) Somehow using iTextSharp to parse the form fields, grab all the form data and save it to the database on submit.

2.) Adding a submit button to the PDF itself using LiveCycle with some sort of JS click event to save the FDF/XFDF/XDP/XML data either to the database or to a flat file on the server.

I am currently unsure as to what the best approach would be, what would work, or how to implement any of these possible solutions, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update:

We've managed to submit PDF form data back to the server, convert the FDF to XML and save to the database. The LiveCycle dynamic PDFs however do not seem to work the same way. When we are submitting the PDF back to the server, we're getting a 500 Internal Server Error. So the process works so far, but only on our static (non-LiveCycle) PDFs.

Any Idea why we might be getting the internal server error on the LiveCycle forms?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to use the Livecycle itself to save the data?

You could setup a service process in LiveCycle to accept the changes in the data from the pdf (which is in XDP/XML), and save that to the database with a sql activity. **This would be your best bet.** This is what LiveCycle is used for, PDf form submission and rendering, mung other things.

If you want more details on ho LC works, I'd be more than happy to give you reference stuff.a

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I assume I would need a copy of LiveCycle installed on the server machine itself? If so, that shouldn't be a problem to get on there.

Do you have any useful resources that can guide me in the direction of how to use LiveCycle to do this?

Comment: PDF are created in LC designer, work flows are created with the workbench. 

Here is a link that goes over the different types of submission for PDFs.
http://www.acrobatusers.com/tutorials/modifying-livecycle-designer-form-submit-button

Here is a link to the forums:
http://forums.adobe.com/community/livecycle

Really all you need to get your hands on for the database inserts, is the XML data itself. Once you have that you can do XML manipulation to get at the data.
If LC is not an option, let me know and I'll continue to help.